# QUERY in ARRAYFORMULA to FILTER and JOIN

Tags: google-sheets

Given a table like this one

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Controvérsia | 1 | Controvérsia 1 |  | Tese |
| 2 | Controvérsia | 1 | Controvérsia 1 | (2017/0154068-7) | Rejeitado |
| 3 | Controvérsia | 1 | Controvérsia 1 | (2016/0278523-9) | Rejeitado |
| 4 | Controvérsia | 2 | Controvérsia 2 |  | Tese |
| 5 | Controvérsia | 2 | Controvérsia 2 | (2017/0201971-0) | Sobrestado |
| 6 | Controvérsia | 2 | Controvérsia 2 | (2016/0290114-1) | Sobrestado |
| 7 | Controvérsia | 2 | Controvérsia 2 | (2016/0309592-1) | Sobrestado |
| 8 | Controvérsia | 3 | Controvérsia 3 |  | Tese |
| 9 | Controvérsia | 3 | Controvérsia 3 | (2016/0313842-4) | Afetado |
| 10 | Controvérsia | 3 | Controvérsia 3 | (2016/0305954-5) | Afetado |

In which Col C has the following arrayformula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A<>"",A2:A&" "&B2:B, ""))
```

As long rows in Col C has the same string Col E should return all its correspondent strings in the same Col F row (the one in which Col E ="Tese")

So, as rows 1 to 3 of Col A strings are "Controvérsia 1", row 1 in Col F should return (with line breaks):

(2017/0154068-7)
(2016/0278523-9)
(2016/0278498-6)

I'm using a dropdown formula to do the job, which is working fine:

```
=IFERROR(IF(E3="Tese", JOIN(CHAR(10),FILTER(D3:D,C3:C=C3,D3:D<>"")),""))
```

But it would be easier if it could be replaced by an ARRAYFORMULA (the table is over 4,000 rows!).

I think it is possible to do it using a QUERY, but I could not write the formula down.

The real table is here:
[LINK](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fQpZcLPIlgv4Q62-2Hfg5gv-5AEZz0AQgmC9Pfm3Dxs/edit#gid=306985279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this in row 1 on empty column:

```
={"Lista de processos e registros completos";""; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E3:E="Tese"; 
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(C3:C; REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 QUERY(QUERY({C3:C&"¤"\IF(D3:D="";;"×"&D3:D)\ROW(D3:D)}; 
 "select Col1,max(Col2) group by Col1 pivot Col3"); 
 "offset 1"; 0));;9^9)); "¤"));"^×"; ); "×"; CHAR(10)); 2; 0)); ))}
```

[image]

### [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/181KHbcJrEqQfCrRd3ocNAvvz5V7CE9pgs_2Qs5HMSmA/edit#gid=306985279)